# Google Assistant SDK "cannot cast" compile error in api/auth.pb.cc

Tags: c++11, makefile, google-oauth, google-assistant-sdk

I tried to compile the new v1alpha2 of the grpc Google Assistant SDK.

For that I ran make (with cpp language output) inside the Google Assistant git repository, which generated my `*.pb.cc` and `*.ob.h` files. Then I tried to compile the `/google/api`, `/google/type` `*.pb.cc` files into `.o` files, that I can link into my basic project. (the `embedded_assistant.proto` has two import statements: `import "google/api/annotations.proto"; import "google/type/latlng.proto";`).

I also tried to compile it with `/google/protobuf` and `/google/rpc`.

It is automated by a `makefile`, and at this command I get the following error:

```
make generated command:
g++ -c -I/usr/local/include -pthread -I./googleapis/gens -I./grpc  -std=c++11 googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.cc -o googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.o

output:
googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.cc:552:23: error: cannot cast '::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::google::api::AuthenticationRule>' to its private base class
    'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase'
rules_.InternalSwap(&other->rules_);
                    ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:776:41: note: declared private here
class RepeatedPtrField PROTOBUF_FINAL : private internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase {
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.cc:553:27: error: cannot cast '::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::google::api::AuthProvider>' to its private base class
    'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase'
providers_.InternalSwap(&other->providers_);
                        ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:776:41: note: declared private here
class RepeatedPtrField PROTOBUF_FINAL : private internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase {
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.cc:936:30: error: cannot cast '::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::google::api::AuthRequirement>' to its private base class
    'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase'
requirements_.InternalSwap(&other->requirements_);
                            ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:776:41: note: declared private here
class RepeatedPtrField PROTOBUF_FINAL : private internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase {
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
make: *** [googleapis/gens/google/api/auth.pb.o] Error 1
```

thanks for any help

Comment: I hit this. Caused by version mixing gRPC and protobufs. Always use the same version of protobufs referenced by the gRPC branch you're building.

Answer (score -1):

I setup everything completly new, now it works. I think maybe some include pathes were wrong. (but i don't really know, why it works now)

1. checkout `https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis`
2. cd into `googleapis` and checkout submodules with `git submodule update --init`
3. run `make LANGUAGE=cpp`
4. compile alle the `*.pb.cc` files in subdirectorys `googleapis/gens/google/api` and `googleapis/gens/google/type` and `googleapis/gens/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2`
5. put them together into an archive
6. link that archive together with `grpc` and `protobuf` librarys and some sample code into an executable. `protobuf` and `grpc` need to be installed, like here in step 3: [c++ v1alpha1 assistant sdk example](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-cpp)

i put this dirty makefile together. not really nice, but does the trick.

```
GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH = ./googleapis/gens

API_CCS = $(shell find ./googleapis/gens/google/api -name '*.pb.cc')

TYPE_CCS = $(shell find ./googleapis/gens/google/type -name '*.pb.cc')

ASSISTANT_CCS = $(shell find ./googleapis/gens/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2 -name '*.pb.cc')

CC = g++

FLAGS += -I$(GOOGLEAPIS_GENS_PATH)
FLAGS += -std=c++11

SRC = $(API_CCS) $(TYPE_CCS) $(ASSISTANT_CCS)

OBJ = $(SRC:%.cc=%.o)

PROG_FLAGS = $(FLAGS)
PROG_FLAGS += `pkg-config --libs grpc++ grpc`
PROG_FLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`
PROG_FLAGS += -I./googleapis/gens/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha2

PROG_SRC = main.cpp
PROG_OBJ = $(PROG_SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: prog

prog: assistant_api.ar $(PROG_SRC)
    $(CC) $(PROG_FLAGS) $(PROG_SRC) assistant_api.ar -o prog

assistant_api.ar: $(OBJ)
    ar r $@ $?

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $*.cc -o $*.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.o assistant_api.ar $(OBJ)
```